# Alert message - target framework is not supported

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When I try to open a project, I receive an alert message stating that the **target framework is not supported**. I have attached a screenshot for your reference.

[image]

System specification :

Operating System: Windows 10.

SDK - Visual Studio 2022.

query :
I am cloning this project from TFS. Choosing the above two solutions may affect the projects.
Is it possible to work on my local system,in VS 2022 without changing the project?

Comment: So what is the issue in fact? I think the modal is self explanatory enough.

Comment: Have you tried pressing continue? Or are there any requirements that you need to use 4.0?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response I have edited my post please look at the query section.

Comment: The error is clear. .NET Framework 4.0 reached End Of Life in 2016. No Windows version or Visual Studio version has it any more, all have more recent versions. All supported Windows versions come with 4.6.2 installed at least

Answer (score -2):

download the reference assemblies, open the file as zip and paste the content of the folder build.NETFramework\Program files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework.